# Email not working when hosted my MVC 4 apllication in GoDaddy

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, email, smtp

I'm trying to send mail from my MVC 4 application which is working fine in my local machine.
But when i deployed my code in GoDaddy email is not working.
It is throwing an erroe like 500 Internal Server Error

My Code is as below

```
MailMessage mail = new MailMessage();
mail.To.Add("support@cubstudios.com");
mail.From = new MailAddress("aravind430@gmail.com");
mail.ReplyTo = new MailAddress("aravind430@gmail.com");
mail.Subject = "Test";
mail.Body = "Hi, This is a test mail.";
mail.IsBodyHtml = true;

SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient();
smtp.Host = "smtpout.asia.secureserver.net";
smtp.Port = 80;
smtp.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
smtp.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("support@cubstudios.com", "******");
smtp.EnableSsl = false;
smtp.Send(mail);
```

Comment: Try testing to see if you can connect to smtpout.asia.secureserver.net on port 80 from the machine that your application is running on, using telnet.  Does it connect?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue.  You must change the port to 25.  Which, this is funny because port 25 will not work locally.  So, it must be port 80 when developing locally and then changed to port 25 after deployment.

You may be able to get around this by changing the CAS priv. to full in the ASP.NET settings.  I haven't tried that though.  I just set my port in the web.config and have it changed depending on the deployment type (DEBUG vs. RELEASE)

Answer (score 0):

When sending email from GoDaddy's web server, you should need to relay-hosting.secureserver.net.